# Как удалить hash(#) из адресной строки

Tags: angular2, typescript

Если убрать из app.module.ts строку `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }` или если заменить на `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }`, все работает правильно, за исключением обновления страницы. Этот вопрос решается, если в файл `.htaccess` добавить строку `ErrorDocument 404 /index.html`, но такой подход кажется не совсем правильным, потому что в консоли все равно видна ошибка `404 (Not Found)`, после ошибки происходит переадресация и все вроде бы хорошо. Нет ли другого способа без ошибки в консоли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

вместо

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```